# How to add extra syntax highlight rule to existing Vim syntax highlighting script?

Tags: vim

I have a syntax highlighting script that is pretty good except I'd like to enhance it without modifying the original file. In particular, it defines an `Identifier` highlight group name:

```
:hi Identifier
Identifier     xxx term=underline ctermfg=208 guifg=#FD971F
```

I'd like to have all words that start with a capital letter ([A-Z]) be highlighted by this. What do I have to add to my .vimrc to get this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more permanent scenarios I prefer to use the syntax commands instead of match, as suggested by @ryuichiro.

Adding something like the following to your vimrc will achieve what you ask for:

```
:au FileType * syntax match Identifier /\<[A-Z].*\>/
```

For more information check the following help page:

```
:help syntax.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`matchadd` should do the trick

```
:au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('Identifier', '\<[A-Z].\{-}\>', -1)
```

- [`:h matchadd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchadd%28%29)